# <form> tag causes error 10053 in django project's ajax request. Why is this happening?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, django

I've commented various things on my html file, and finally I've found that using the form tag around my input and button tags is causing

```
[Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

in my django project when I click on the button to do an ajax request. However, when I comment out the form tag, it works totally fine. I was using the form tag because it was a part of a bootstrap template code snippet I grabbed from somewhere. I've switched to a span tag now, but I'd really like to know how the form tag was causing so many problems?

The code snippet is as follows:

```
    <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
              <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a href = '#'>About</a></li>
                <li><a href = '#'>Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
                  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                      <span class="input-group">
                          <input type="text"  class = "form-control inputAB" id="addBook" placeholder = "Add a Book" >
                          <span class="input-group-btn">
                              <button class="btn btn-default" id="addBookButton">Submit</button>
                          </span>
                      </span>
                  </form>
                <ul  class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><a id="bookInfo">book</a></li>
                </ul>
          </div>
```

Comment: You're not sending the csrf token.

Comment: but my view has the @csrf_exempt decorator around the method that the ajax call hits

Comment: Or, how exactly would you implement this? I was thinking <form method="post">{% csrf_token %} but that still gives me the same error. Design wise, I'd like to form over span because span causes bootstrap to make some random unwanted lines in the navbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZOMG! I've figured it out.. I should've also posted my view functions in my original post. I didn't return an HttpResponse()... LOL!